# Constructor chaining. Why should I initialize a parameter in this()

Tags: java

I have a class presented below. And I have a question: why should I initialize the third parameter in this(name, sal, "Gurgaon"); in the third constructor public Employee1(String name, int sal) ? I mean why i can't put "addr" instead of initializing the third parameter--> this(name, sal, addr); ?

```
public class Employee1 {
    public String name;
    public int salary;
    public String address;

    //default constructor of the class
    public Employee1()
    {
        //this will call the constructor with String param
        this("Chaitanya");
        System.out.println("Default");
    }

    public Employee1(String name)
    {
        //call the constructor with (String, int) param
        this(name, 120035);
        System.out.println(name);
    }
    public Employee1(String name, int sal)
    {
        //call the constructor with (String, int, String) param
        this(name, sal, "Gurgaon");
        System.out.println(name + " " + sal);
    }
    public Employee1(String name, int sal, String addr)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.salary=sal;
        this.address=addr;
        System.out.println(name + " "+ sal + " " + addr);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Employee1 obj = new Employee1();
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m not sure about your question..Is this your code or sth else? This code seems to be a sample of constructor with parameters, therefore, the parameter declarations could be just for demostration only

Comment: `public Employee1(String name, int sal)` is not the second constructor, it's the third constructor. And if you don't want to initialise something, who says you have to?

Comment: It's my error about "second constructor". Actually I mean third one. I edited the question with this correction. Thank you!

Comment: @Nhon Dinh, it's just a sample to understand how chaining works.

Comment: You can do that. It is not clear what you are asking. Beyond that: obviously a bad example. You only use such defaults in case you have meaningful defaults. Names shouldnt default.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't call the last constructor with address as a parameter, then your second last constructor would like this:

```
  public Employee1(String name, int sal)
  {
    //call the constructor with (String, int, String) param
    this.address = "Gurgaon";
    System.out.println(name + " "+ sal + " " + address);
  }
```

If address is not initialized here, address would be printed out as null. So, like mentioned in the comment above, you don't have to call the final constructor or even need to have one if you don't want to.

Comment: thank your! Could you clarify please one more thing-->I mean why i can't put "addr" instead of initializing the third parameter--> this(name, sal, addr); ?

Comment: Because you haven't yet initialized `addr` variable, so at this time addr is `null`. So, "Gurgaon" needs to be assigned to instance variable `address` to get this variable value later. So, you can use either initialize the variable like your way         `this(name, sal, "Gurgaon");` or like I assigned     `this.address = "Gurgaon";`